# NSLayoutConstraint for a UILabel to "grow" extra lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UILabel` and I would like to set it so that it has a fixed width and variable height dependant on its `text` rather than its `superView`.

i.e. if the `text` is "Hello World." then the label will be...

```
------------------------
|Hello World.          |
------------------------
```

and if the `text` is "This is some very long text that goes over several lines." Then the label will be...

```
------------------------
|This is some very long|
|text that goes over   |
|several lines.        |
------------------------
```

I have already set the fixed width using an `NSLayoutConstraint` and I have set `numberOfLines` to 0 but it just keep one line height and concatenates the text with an ellipsis.

I know that there is something called "contentResistance" or something but I'm not sure of the name or how to use it.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of the label, to your fixed width. I don't know why it can't figure this out for itself since you've constrained to a width, but there you go.

If having to set a fixed size feels wrong in an Autolayout world (which it should!) then you can set the value from the label's width *after* layout has occurred, in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Be careful not to get into an infinite loop of invalidating your layout in this case.

Comment: This works thanks. It feels wrong though to have AUTO layout and give a UILabel a preferred width. The "fixed" width of the label that I have is dependant on the width of its superView. However the preferredMaxLayoutWidth is now a constant. Oh well, in this case the superView won't change so it won't matter, lol.

Comment: I agree! For a more dynamic layout you can set the value in viewDidLayoutSubviews and base it off the bounds width.

Answer (score -2):

Try This code it may helpful to You>

```
   label.text=@"haiiiiiiiii";

    UIFont *cellFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
    CGSize constraintSize=CGSizeMake(250,MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize txtViewSize=[label.text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

yourlabelname.numberOfLines=0;

CGRect frame=yourlabelname.frame;

```
frame.size.width=250;

frame.size.height=txtViewSize.height;

yourlabelname.frame=frame;

yourlabelname.text=cellText;
```

Comment: I'm using AutoLayout so I can't change the frame directly. Thanks though.